# py2app error:is a directory

Tags: python, py2app, sourceforge-appscript

When i execute the following command in terminal:

```
python setup.py py2app
```

it ends with :

```
byte-compiling /Users/gebruiker/Documents/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-
semi_standalone/app/temp/aem/ae.py to aem/ae.pyc
error: Is a directory
```

The error is : error: Is a directory - how can I solve this error ?

and no .app will be created in the dist folder...

I'm using the following setup.py (and i'm using appscript in my source code) :

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""


from setuptools import setup
from appscript import *

APP = ['schermen1.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Does anybody have any clue how I can solve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  What fixed it for me was specifying to py2app the packages that my python code imported. I did this as a '--package' argument:

```
python setup.py py2app --packages <package>
```